# Touchpad won't drag anything on a Pavilion dv7t-5000

Tags: touchpad, hp

Okay so I have a pavilion dv7t-5000 cto. First question is how do i get the correct drivers for my touch pad. I cant click with the touch pad button and drag the box.

I have to use a mouse or click the top of the box and hit the move command and drag it (pain in the butt!) i have the synaptics drivers installed but no resolution

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: Does it work if you tap twice and hold the second tap ?

Answer (score 1):

On my laptop and netbook, to drag a window, tap twice on the title bar and hold the second tap.